# Google Apps Script .getLastColumn(); of a specific row?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I basically want to get the last column of the first row of a spreadsheet.  No matter what I try it Logs the last column with data of the whole spreadsheet.  I know it's pretty simple, but no luck.

I have searched all over and everything I try doesn't work.  Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks so much!
Brandon

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code to get you started:

```
function getLastNonEmptyCellInRow() {
  var rowToCheck = 2;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var maxColumns = sheet.getLastRow();

  var rowData = sheet.getRange(rowToCheck, 1, 1, maxColumns).getValues();
  rowData = rowData[0]; //Get inner array of two dimensional array

  var rowLength = rowData.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
    var thisCellContents = rowData[i];

    Logger.log('thisCellContents: ' + thisCellContents);

    if (thisCellContents === "") {
      Logger.log(i);
      return i + 1;  //Pass the count plus one, which is the last column with data
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Changed `getMaxRows()` to `.getLastRow()`.. Max Rows can return 1000 rows even if you only have a few rows of data.

Comment: Awesome thanks.  Any way to get it to ignore cells that have formulas? Also,  anyway to use this new found number of rows as a variable in a range? Basically,  I have a sheet of data that has a header row of 1-40 with data underneath.  I was trying to create a chart using this data, but couldn't use lastcolumn() because of the numbered header row.  Now that you were able to brilliantly find that last column with data,  I'd like to try and use it in a range so that chart is always just looking at the range with data and ignoring the header row.  Thanks.

Comment: To many questions for the comments section.  I'm guessing that the data needs to be retrieved in parts, then assembled into one array, then use the array as the data source for the chart instead of a range.  But I'm just making a wild guess.

Comment: Sorry about the number of questions, I'll look into that.  Thanks again for all of your time.

Comment: You can always post another question.  Try to make it specific.  Feel free to look at my profile and contact me if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getLastColNum(rowNum)
{
  // Get the values of the row's (unbounded by column number) range.
  var vals =
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
        .getRange(rowNum +":"+ rowNum)
        .getValues()[0],

      lastColNum = vals.length
  ;

  // Decrement while popping off any trailing empty text ("") cells.
  while(!vals.pop())
  { --lastColNum; }


  return(lastColNum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in function to do this, but you can write a function to do it yourself.

For example,  use getRange() and getLastColumn() to get the row you are interested in up to the last possible data column, then use getValues() to get all the cells in that row. Finally, loop over array of cells (returned by getValues()) and keep track of the last index which has a value.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange()

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()

Comment: To really test the last row, you also have to check for formulas. Because if a formula returns an empty string, you wouldn't detect it only with `getValues()`, and therefore would assume a wrong last row.

Comment: @Henrique G. Abreu That may have been an issue in the past, but I tested with a Sheet that has validation and validation not an issue for the code I posted.

Answer (score 0):

The Sheet class supports getLastColumn() to return the last column with content in it.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastColumn()

Range has a getLastColumn() function, but it is the last column of the range and not necessarily the last column with data in it.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getLastColumn()

To get the last column with content in it, iterate over the row from the last Sheet column back to a non-empty cell.

```
   /**
   * Get last column with content in row
   * @param {Sheet} sheet
   * @param {integer} row
   * @return {integer} last column with content, 0 if none found
   */
   function getLatColInRow(sheet, row = 1) {
       let lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
       let values = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,lastColumn).getValues()[0];
       while ((values[lastColumn-1] == "") && (lastColumn>0)) {
           lastColumn --;
       }
       return lastColumn;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

from excel workbook object get sheet using getSheetAt(sheetNumber); then using sheet object getRow(0);  then using cellIterator() you can iterate till last column of row.
Example using XSSFWorkBook 
XSSFWorkBook wb=new XSSFWorkBook(FileInputStream object);//object got by passing excel file path to FileInputStream Sheet sh=wb.getSheetAt(0) or wb.getSheet("sheet name"); Row row=sh.getRow(0); Iterator cit=row.cellIterator();Cell cell; while(cit.hasNext()) { cell=cit.next(); }

when you come out of the while loop you will have last cell object in 'cell' variable

Comment: please consider formatting your code, it's almost impossible to read how it is now.